Why Print function is splitting my Pandas DataFrame?
I was experimenting with the pandas in Google Colab. However, during one of my trials, the DataFrame got a slightly bigger side-wise. I used the following:
## Assign ranks to employees based on their salaries within their respective departments.

df['Salary_Rank'] = df.groupby('Department')['Salary'].transform(lambda x: x.rank(ascending=False))

print(df)

And the output is broken into like the following:

There is plenty of space by the side but it's still breaking the DataFrame for output.
Questions:

Is it a Google Colab issue?
Any way to print the DataFrame as expected (side-by-side)?


Try using pd.options.display.width = 500

@ScottBoston Perfectly worked.
